# How many times following loop will iterate in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, while-loop

```
int a = 1;
while (a < 20) {
    if ((++a % 3) == 0)
        System.out.println(“Divisible 3”);
    else if ((a++ % 3) > 0)
        System.out.println(“Not Divisible 3”);
    else break;
}
```

I'm not a programme exaper, i need the solution on this question.
How many times following loop will iterate?

Comment: How about running it? ;)

Comment: Does this translate to: *"I am being asked this question in an interview and I want this job but I don't have any clue about the basic concepts of programming."*

Comment: oh its I'm not a programme expert @Ducan

Comment: This is not for an interview @ Fiburt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count = 0;
int a = 1;
while (a < 20) {
   count++;
   if ((++a % 3) == 0)
      System.out.println("Divisible 3");
   else if ((a++ % 3) > 0)
      System.out.println("Not Divisible 3");
      else break;
   }
System.out.println("count = " + count);
```

Output:

```
Not Divisible 3
Not Divisible 3
Divisible 3
Not Divisible 3
Divisible 3
Not Divisible 3
Divisible 3
Not Divisible 3
Divisible 3
Not Divisible 3
Divisible 3
Not Divisible 3

count = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result:

Loop runs 12 times

```
 3 Not Divisible 3
 5 Not Divisible 3
 6 Divisible 3
 8 Not Divisible 3
 9 Divisible 3
11 Not Divisible 3
12 Divisible 3
14 Not Divisible 3
15 Divisible 3
17 Not Divisible 3
18 Divisible 3
20 Not Divisible 3
```